# Install packages locally with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am new with Node and **npm**, and when I try to install packages locally, all of the dependencies for that specific package gets installed in the main **nodule_modules** folder.

It looks like this

[LOCALLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjrTe.png)

And if I install them globally it looks like this

[GLOBALLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnmbN.png)

I think I should mention the fact that the folder where I try to install locally is on Desktop.

Comment: To install globally, try `npm install -g` and for local, just use `npm install`

Comment: This is what I did, but it looks like this

Comment: What are you trying to do then?

Comment: I just don't understand why at local installing the dependencies for every package is not inside them, but in the main node_modules folder like in the picture. I want them to look like in the picture where they are installed globally.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Can you say why it matters how the dependencies are organised?  Is this causing you a problem?

Comment: Because I am thinking if they are organised like this, then the require won't work properly. Maybe I am not right. Please tell me if so.

Comment: As of [npm version 3.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0) they've choose to use a flat dependency tree; and here is how it works: https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3

Answer (score 0):

If you need to install specific dependancies for a project you are working on then do it locally:

```
npm install <packagename>
```

If you need something that you can run from the commandline such as `grunt` or `phantomjs` (etc..) then install it globally:

```
npm install -g <packagename>
```